# Make Azure VM image publically deployable

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have have created a Resource Manager VM image in Azure and this is publically  accessible from the web and can be downloaded.

From what I can see, users can download this image if they wanted to and upload it into their Azure subscription.

Is it possible to deploy this image from our Azure blob storage, from the PowerShell examples and .NET SDK it says it has to be in the same subscription and location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is correct, you need to first copy the image to a storage account in the subscription where you want to create the VM from.

The alternative, and sounds like it might meet your objective, is to publish the image into the marketplace.  You can also provide an ARM template to allow users to configure it before deployment.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/marketplace-publishing-vm-image-creation/

For an walkthrough on creating ARM templates (not VMs but the same tools/principals apply) - please see my blog post https://russellyoung.net/2016/04/15/arm-cd-vsts/

Comment: Do you have a link on how to submit to market place and create a template? I've seen the templates that can be exported but not how it all fits together. Thanks

Comment: Added in main post.  Templates are easy and really useful - I have a blog post [https://russellyoung.net/2016/04/15/arm-cd-vsts/](https://russellyoung.net/2016/04/15/arm-cd-vsts/) which includes walking through creating a template (for a web app rather than a VM, but the process and tools are the same).

Comment: I've had a look at this today and it azure article you posted it looks like it switchs between Resource Manager VMs and Classic. I'm looking at step 5 and the details required look like they are for a classic VM not a resource manager VM

Comment: If I get time to go through the process I'll give it a go.  The VHD is generic, its the way in which the image is deployed that will make it ARM (v2) or Classic - hence why when you go to the marketplace and choose a VM image, you usually get the option of Resource Manager or Classic Deployment for the same image.

Comment: Thanks, its just step 5 thats thrown me.